# Intensive use of lists in configuration files

Tags: java, refactoring, configuration-files

While refactoring some legacy system (java), I came across a configuration files that make intensive use of lists.
Mostly, there is a property that defines list of references parameters, and afterward there are properties with corresponding values, such as:

```
referencesNames = name1, name2, ...
valuesList1 = name1Value, name2Value, ...
valuesList2 = name1Value, name2Value, ...
```

The problem - there are too many lists and they are too long.

One thought of mine was to eliminate the references lists and create something like that:

```
name1Values = value1, value2, ...
name2Values = value1, value2, ...
```

Nevertheless these lists are still long, and it's hard to define their values correctly.
Also, the references names are now hardcoded, so if I want to add a new one, I must open the code to handle the corresponding property. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you provide some more statistical information; it may help with regards to coming up with possible solution(s).

Comment: @Juxhin Most of the references lists contain 10-20 names (some contain 50 names), and there is approximately 20-30 corresponding lists to each one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common choices for configuration files in Java: `Properties` and XML.

Converting to XML is a bit more involved, but allows more complex configurations. Exactly what the XML looks like is up to you, but here's an example:

```xml
<Configuration>
    <Reference name="name1">
        <Value1>name1Value</Value1>
        <Value2>name1Value</Value2>
        ...
    </Reference>
    ...
</Configuration>
```

Staying with a property file, those lists can be eliminated by using qualified names:

```
Value1.name1    name1Value
Value2.name1    name1Value
```

Or the other way around:

```
name1.Value1    name1Value
name1.Value2    name1Value
```